# Deleting table row by id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dont't get why this code isn't working. Table row should be removed, but it's not. Confirm box is showing ok.

Maybe I have something wrong with row id or `var elementId` - I'm not sure.

```
<table> // some table code missing in this example because it's not necessary
    <tr id="orderEmpty" style="display: none;"><td><i class="text-muted">No items.</i></td></tr>
    <tr id="00001"><td><a href="#" onclick="deleteRow('00001')">Delete</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

```js
<script>
    function deleteRow($rowToDel) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure? Delete row from order?");
        if (result) {
            var elementId = $rowToDel;
            var rowCount = $('#orderTable tbody tr').length;
            if (rowCount < 3) {
                $('#' + $rowToDel + '').closest('tr').remove();
                $("#orderEmpty").fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#' + $rowToDel + '').closest('tr').remove();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, change `$('#' + $rowToDel + '').closest('tr').remove();` to `$('#' + $rowToDel).remove();`

Comment: won't help: closest: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing **the element itself** and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: The `.closest()` function includes the starting element, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console? Do you have more than one `<tr>` with the same id value?

Comment: [Your code seems to be working just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/mff5vcpu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code as given already works for me; please see this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v30fv89t/

I suspect that the actual markup you're working with is longer, but in the example you gave, `rowCount` will always be `0` because there is no `#orderTable` or `tbody`, and so that branch will always execute when `deleteRow()` is called.

If you can, please post a more extensive version of your markup - at least extensive enough so that your code fully tests against the markup you're working with.

Comment: I didn't noticed that I had select box on same page using same ids as table rows. So that was one problem. I have `#orderTable` and `tbody` but I shortened the code for the question. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `.closest('tr')` it should work. You already select the `tr` you're trying to delete with the jQuery constructor.

Also `+ ''` is unnecessary as int is converted to a sting when it's added to one (in this case `'#'`).

Comment: The `.closest()` function includes the starting element, so that shouldn't be a problem.